# Request to filter a table

Tags: postgresql, group

i search the right query to have only the last accident by month.
My structure :

id, Month, year, N°accident of month ,date,detail

1, January,2020,1,01/01/20,Head

2,January,2020,2,10/01/20,foot

3,January,2020,3,21/01/20,foot

4,february,2020,1,04/02/20,hand

5,march,2020,1,04/02/20,finger

6,march,2020,2,05/02/20,foot

7,august,2020,1,05/08/20,head

The result:

3,January,2020,3,21/01/20,foot

4,february,2020,1,04/02/20,hand

6,march,2020,2,05/02/20,foot

7,august,2020,1,05/08/20,head

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you please construct a fiddle - dbfiddle.uk.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve only the last accident by month from your database structure, you can use SQL. You'll need to group the records by month and year and then select the record with the maximum date within each group. Here's the SQL query for your case:

```
SELECT id, Month, year, N°accident, date, detail
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Month, year ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
  FROM your_table_name
) AS ranked
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Make sure to replace your_table_name with the actual name of your table. This query uses a subquery with the ROW_NUMBER() window function to assign a row number to each record within each month and year partition based on the date in descending order. Then, it selects only the rows where the row number is 1, which corresponds to the latest accident in each month and year.

The result will be the last accident for each month and year in your dataset.